# How to center the TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

I would like to design the table of contents aligned to a vertical line near the center of the page. The chapter and section titles need to be flushright, the numbers flushleft, and between titles and numbers, I'd like to place a separating element. It can be done easily by a tabular:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}m{0.4\textwidth}>{\centering}m{0.3cm}>{\raggedright}m{0.4\textwidth}}
First section title & \textbullet & 27 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

You can see the result of the code above on this image:

[image]

But how can I build a tabular with the LaTeX `\tableofcontents` command? What commands do I need to redefine? After some googling I haven't found any ready solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the chapter insert any symbol you like, instead of the `\Large\textbullet`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\def\MBox#1#2#3#4{%
  \parbox[t]{0.4\linewidth}{\RaggedLeft#1}%
  \makebox[0.1\linewidth]{\color{red}#2}%
  \makebox[0.4\linewidth][l]{#3}\\[#4]}
\renewcommand*\l@chapter   [2]{\par\MBox{\bfseries\Large#1}{\Large\textbullet}{#2}{5pt}}
\renewcommand*\l@section   [2]{    \MBox{\bfseries\large#1}{\textbullet}{#2}{2pt}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection[2]{    \MBox{\bfseries      #1}{\textbullet}{#2}{1pt}}
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{foo}
\newpage
\section{bar}
\newpage
\subsection{foobar}
foobar
\section{An extraordinary long section title which should have a linebreak
         in the table of contents}
bar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wonderful, thanks! i have never thought that it's so simple.

Answer (score 1):

- Redefine `\tableofcontents` to produce the tabular environment
- Redefine `\l@chapter`, `\l@section` etc. to produce the rows of the table. These macros take two arguments. Use [`makeatletter` and `\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do).

Have a look into the source of your document class, where all mentioned macros are defined. The source is on your local drive, use your search feature or `kpsewhich` to locate it, such as

```
kpsewhich book.cls
```

at the command prompt. On Linux, I often directly use it like

```
gedit `kpsewhich book.cls`
```

Actually, I made a shell function for that, to ease the frequent access of source code.

Comment: thank you! maybe i'll try also this way, because the vertical centering of the numbers in the case of section titles wrapped to more line.